# Get xml value by element name

Tags: java, xml, string

How can i get XML value by attribute for the below XML:

I have tried:

```
String xml = "<Info><document><document>234doc</document></document></Info>";

 Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
        .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

NodeList errNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("error");
if (errNodes.getLength() > 0) {
    Element err = (Element)errNodes.item(0);
} else { 
    Node value = doc.getElementsByTagName("document").item(0);
    out.println(value);
}
```

I am looking for the output: "234doc". But I am not sure how do get the value. Can any one please suggest?

Comment: It's worth being precise in your terminology here - you don't have any attributes at all. You're trying to get the value of an element by its *element name*. Now, what *are* you seeing at the moment? Note that you're only examining the first `document` element, and you've got two - one inside the other.

Comment: @JonSkeet edited my title..How do i get the value by elements?

Comment: Did you read the rest of my comment? First I'd concentrate on getting the right element. Then `Node.getTextContent()` is probably your friend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a rocket science. You should debug your code, explore classes you might already know (*Document, NodeList, Node, Element*) and understand your xml structure (for more info look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/TOC.html)). One way to achieve your result is:

```
System.out.println(doc.getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent());
```